# Sheets: use FILTER for multiple strings instead of exact match only?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to SUM column C based on the contents of columns A and B. Like this:

```
=sum(filter(C:C, (A:A="Safari")*(B:B="10.0.1")))
```

The above formula works. The FILTER function works as an exact match for "Safari" and "10.0.1" for columns A and B respectively.

The problem is... this only captures an exact match: "10.0.1". I need to capture multiple strings e.g. "10.0.1", "10.0.2", "10.0.3", etc.

If helpful, here's an [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bZRImEM3wFv6cgMdKV1eoZKxohs7BKsr3ySZskhaol4/edit?usp=sharing).

I'm not sure if regex can be used in combination with a filter function. In any case, I've tried hard and failed spectacularly. So... how best to filter for **multiple strings** instead of exact match only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"Safari",B:B,"10.0.*")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

`=filter(C:C, (A:A="Safari")*(REGEXMATCH(B:B, "10\.0\..*")))`

Notes:

- `filter` is an `arrayformlula` and it has a great property: it converts all the formulas inside it into array formulas
- "10.0..*" is a regex for your match. `"\."` will match a dot, `".*"` will match any sequence of chars. Please see [more syntax here](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt).

Comment: Thanks - this works but it doesn't sum the total. Rather, it pulls the values into individual cells without summing the aggregate total.

Comment: I gave an idea of a formula. It may be used with any aggregation: `=sum(original_formula)` or `max`, `min`, `average`.